# TFS Release Notes and work items within Builds

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I am running automated builds each night which are working fine.

I am trying to get a report of which Work Items have been completed as part of the over night build.

I am currently using TF.EXE history * /recursive /v:d$.......

Which is greate for Change Sets, but these change set are of no use for the release team, as they need to know the workitems.

Any ideas on how I can get the Work Items report?

Comment: are you associating workitems on checkin?

Comment: Yes I am association the workitems with the checkin

Answer (score 1):

If you're using TFS in the right way, it should provide this information for you automatically.  If you make sure all checkins are associated with a work item then, when you run the build, you will see a list of work items associated with a build.

That list of items is maintained separately for each build type, so if you make sure that your "nightly build" is a different build definition to (for example) your CI build, you should find that you get the list you're looking for.

Extracting that information for reporting purposes may be more difficult - but I'd imagine it's possible to either extract this from the build log or insert a custom build step to write the information out to a file.

Comment: Where can I get to see this information, I've check the on the build server, but I can only get View Summary, View Log, Retain Indefinitely, and Delete Build.

Comment: There should be a associated workitems section in the summary underneath the associated checkins section.

Comment: @Betty - I think you only get the workitems and checkins if you're not using the UpgradeTemplate.xaml for the build.